# Building an HTML5 iOS app with UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, safari, uiwebview

I have a client who suggested we simply wrap an HTML5 app as a native iOS app by just creating a UIWebView and offloading all of the application-logic to the HTML5 app.  This would allow us to have a "native" iOS app and a good mobile app for other devices.

However, this strikes me as a little odd and I was wondering what the pitfalls of such a plan would be.  Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Thanks,
Trey

Comment: Overall the HTML5 experience is lacking compared to the native experience (see Facebook switching to native).  However, if you're simply looking to get into the app store and already have an HTML5 web app, it's obviously a huge time saver.  I've heard many people complain about PhoneGap and other wrappers.  There is a huge debate going online right now about this, but I'd say it really depends on how important the user experience is.  LinkedIn's app is HTML5 with Backbone/Node and you can tell, but it does work.  So there are opinions on both sides.

Answer (score 10):

Any pitfalls you would experience as a web app you are likely to still experience. Don't attempt to do any OpenGL sort of app but if it's more like a webpage then this should work out fine for you.

However, using some frameworks out there you are likely to get a slightly "richer" experience in that you are able to access native phone tools that a web app isn't allowed to use (vibrate, GPS, etc.)

Take a look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/). They lack extensive documentation but there are quite a number of people using it and have already 'ran it through the gauntlet', you could say.

All that said, if you don't want to deal with the marketplaces (iTunes, Android Marketplace, etc) you could always do an offline HTML5 app. Where the user goes to the webpage and it caches all the files that are required to run the app offline. This is a similar approach to what *Google* was doing with *Google Voice* when it was rejected from the iTunes store.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 features within a WebView are really great (and growing). You can do almost everything.

But if you want use some special features inaccessible via HTML5 (or include some 3rd-party ObjC libraries), you can setup a very simple [interaction between ObjC and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge).

Answer (score 0):

Trigger.io is an option too. Much better than Phonegap these days. Only adding as this page is heavily google-SEOed.