# Building a downloadable iOS web app

Tags: android, ios, xcode, web-applications, uiwebview

I gather from [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html) that it's possible to use the `WebView` framework build an Android web app that can then be run on the device without using a web browser.

My question is: is the same possible for iOS, possibly through the UIWebView object?

Comment: Yes, it is. possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249816/building-an-html5-ios-app-with-uiwebview for details.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the link talk about:

> You can make your web content available to users in two ways: in a traditional web browser and in an Android application, by including a WebView in the layout.

With this you can implement a javascript bridge and catch javascript event in android java contest.
iOS allow the same. UIWebView can catch javascript event and work with it.

The most cross platform sdk for mobile development use this feauture to realize the application in javascript and work it in a selfcontained webView.

[Use this to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873899/javascript-in-uiwebview-callback-to-c-objective-c)